# Cannot retrieve struct from JSON in Rust

Tags: json, rust

I'm having problems obtaining a struct from reading a JSON file.
This is how the config file looks like:

**config.json**

```
{
  "config_group_1":{
    "variable_1": 10
  }
}
```

Its `struct` is define as:

```
pub struct ConfigGroup1 {
    variable_1: usize
}

pub struct MainConfig {
    config_group_1: ConfigGroup1
}
```

I'm reading the file with a function that returns `String` in `config_content`.

```
let config: Result = serde_json::from_str(&config_content);
```

But the compiler is pointing to the following error:

```
missing generics for type alias `serde_json::Result`

expected 1 type argument

help: use angle brackets to add missing type argument: `<T>`rustc(E0107)
```

How can I solve this? Where to define that MainConfig is the expected type?

Comment: `let config: MainConfig = serde_json::from_str(&config_content);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a lot is missing. I suggest you read the following documentation https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/

Below is a version that might help you

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::Result;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MainConfig {
    config_group_1: ConfigGroup1
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ConfigGroup1 {
    variable_1: usize
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let data = r#"{"config_group_1": {"variable_1": 10 }}"#;

    let p: MainConfig = serde_json::from_str(data).expect("JSON was not well-formatted");
    println!("Value {} ", p.config_group_1.variable_1);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This does not works: the trait bound `main_config::MainConfig: serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied

the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `main_config::MainConfig`rustc(E0277)

Comment: Zeppi, I was able to resolve it, but where you have a "?" I had to replace for ".expect("JSON was not well-formatted")" and in the TOML I just added "serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }". If you want to edit your answer I can accept it. Thank you by the way